# How apply await in request a web?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I have this code, i want do a request a url

```
if(!m.sendRequest()){
             appDelegate.setValues()
        }
```

this line is executed first

```
  appDelegate.setValues()
```

i want wait this condition

```
!m.sendRequest()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

structure `sendRequest` with a completion

```
 func sendRequest(com:@escaping((Bool) -> ())) {
   Api.sendReq {
       com(true)
   }
 }
```

---

```
sendRequest { value in 
    if value  {
       appDelegate.setValues() 
    }
 }
```